# Accessing the underlying struct of a PyObject

Tags: python, c, pointers, structure

I am working on creating a python c extension but am having difficulty finding documentation on what I want to do. I basically want to create a pointer to a cstruct and be able to have access that pointer. The sample code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
typedef struct{
 int x;
 int y;
} Point;

typedef struct {
 PyObject_HEAD
 Point* my_point;
} PointObject;

static PyTypeObject PointType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                         /*ob_size*/
    "point",             /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(PointObject), /*tp_basicsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_itemsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_dealloc*/
    0,                         /*tp_print*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_compare*/
    0,                         /*tp_repr*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_number*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_sequence*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_mapping*/
    0,                         /*tp_hash */
    0,                         /*tp_call*/
    0,                         /*tp_str*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_buffer*/
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,        /*tp_flags*/
    "point objects",           /* tp_doc */
};

static PyObject* set_point(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
 PyObject* point; 

 if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &point))
 {
  return NULL;
 }

    //code to access my_point    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PyArg_ParseTuple` should not use format `O` but `O!` (see the docs):

```
O! (object) [typeobject, PyObject *]
```

> Store a Python object in a C object
>   pointer. This is similar to O, but
>   takes two C arguments: the first is
>   the address of a Python type object,
>   the second is the address of the C
>   variable (of type PyObject*) into
>   which the object pointer is stored. If
>   the Python object does not have the
>   required type, TypeError is raised.

Once you've done that, you know that in your function's body `(PointObject*)point` will be a correct and valid pointer to a `PointObject`, and therefore its `->my_point` will be the `Point*` you seek.  With a plain format `O` you'd have to do the type checking yourself.

**Edit**: the OP in a comments asks for the source...:

```
static PyObject*
set_point(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* point; 

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PointType, &point))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    Point* pp = ((PointObject*)point)->my_point;

    // ... use pp as the pointer to Point you were looking for...

    // ... and incidentally don't forget to return a properly incref'd
    // PyObject*, of course;-)
}
```

Comment: Alex, could I get the source for how to do this I am still a little lost.

Comment: OK, @user, I just edited my A to add the source code as you request.