# How to determine struct used to declare the instance layout of PyObject?

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, pyobject

I'm writing Python 3 extensions in C++ and I'm trying to find a way to check if a `PyObject` is related to a type (struct) defining its instance layout. I'm only interested in static-size `PyObject`, not `PyVarObject`. The instance layout is defined by a struct with certain well-defined layout: mandatory `PyObject` header and (optional) user-defined members.

Below, is example of `PyObject` extension based on the well-known [Noddy example in Defining New Types](http://docs.python.org/py3k/extending/newtypes.html):

```
// Noddy struct specifies PyObject instance layout
struct Noddy {
    PyObject_HEAD
    int number;
};

// type object corresponding to Noddy instance layout
PyTypeObject NoddyType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                         /*ob_size*/
    "noddy.Noddy",             /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(Noddy),             /*tp_basicsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_itemsize*/
    ...
    Noddy_new,                 /* tp_new */
};
```

It is important to notice that the `Noddy` is a type, a compile-time entity,
but `NoddyType` is an object present in memory at run-time.
The only obvious relation between the `Noddy` and `NoddyType` seems to be
value of `sizeof(Noddy)` stored in `tp_basicsize` member.

The hand-written inheritance implemented in Python specifies rules which allow to cast between `PyObject` and type used to declare the instance layout of that particular `PyObject`:

```
PyObject* Noddy_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    // When a Python object is a Noddy instance,
    // its PyObject* pointer can be safely cast to Noddy
    Noddy *self = reinterpret_cast<Noddy*>(type->tp_alloc(type, 0));

    self->number = 0; // initialise Noddy members

    return reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(self);
}
```

In circumstances like various slot functions, it is safe to assume "a Python object is a Noddy" and cast without any checks.
However, sometimes it is necessary to cast in other situations, then it feels like a blind conversion:

```
void foo(PyObject* obj)
{
    // How to perform safety checks?
    Noddy* noddy = reinterpret_cast<Noddy*>(obj);
    ...
}
```

It is possible to check `sizeof(Noddy) == Py_TYPE(obj)->tp_basicsize`, but it is insufficient solution due to:

1) If a user will derive from `Noddy`

```
class BabyNoddy(Noddy):
    pass
```

and `obj` in `foo` points to instance of the `BabyNoddy`, `Py_TYPE(obj)->tp_basicsize` is diferent.
But, it is still safe to cast to `reinterpret_cast<Noddy*>(obj)` to get pointer to the instance layout part.

2) There can be other struct declaring instance layout of the same size as `Noddy`:

```
struct NeverSeenNoddy {
    PyObject_HEAD
    short word1;
    short word2;
};
```

In fact, C langauge level, `NeverSeenNoddy` struct is compatible with the `NoddyType` type object - it can fit into `NoddyType`. So, cast could be perfectly fine.

So, my big question is this:

Is there any Python policy which could be used to determine if a `PyObject` is compatible with the `Noddy` instance layout?

Any way to check if `PyObject*` points to the object part which is embedded in the `Noddy`?

If not policy, is there any hack possible?

EDIT: There are a few questions which seem to be similar, but in my opinion they are different to the one I have asked. For example: [Accessing the underlying struct of a PyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436730/accessing-the-underlying-struct-of-a-pyobject)

EDIT2: In order to understand why I marked Sven Marnach's response as the answer, see comments below that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, you can check if `obj` is of type `Noddy` or a derived type by using the test `isinstance(obj, Noddy)`.  The test in the C-API whether some `PyObject *obj` is of type `NoddyType` or a derived type is basically the same, you use [`PyObject_IsInstance()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/object.html#PyObject_IsInstance):

```
PyObject_IsInstance(obj, &NoddyType)
```

As for your second question, there is no way to achieve this, and if you think you need this, your design has severe shortcomings.  It would be better to derive `NeverSeenNoddyType` from `NoddyType` in the first place -- then the above check will also recognize an object of the derived type as an instance of `NoddyType`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know PyObject_IsInstance (and all other API working with types) and they don't provide solution to my question. As you have indicated, they check against NoddyType (run-time object), but I'm asking about checking if obj is related to C++ type Noddy (see struct in my example) - struct Noddy is PyObject extension, defines instance layout of PyObject.

Comment: @mloskot: Maybe my answer is not very clear.  You ask essentially to questions, marked with 1) and 2) in your post.  `PyObject_IsInstance()` is the answer to 1).  Regarding 2), this seems a design problem to me.  If you want to do something like this, make sure all types participating have a common base type.  This is my answer to question 2).  So how does this not answer your question?  (Note that I'm aware that 1) and 2) don't actually enumerate questions but rather problematic cases in your post.)

Comment: +1 as your answer does help. These are issues I also discuss, but my question actually is "Any way to check if `PyObject*` points to the object part which is embedded in the Noddy". Analogy from C++ world would be: is there any static-type property in `PyObject` that mimics `struct PyObject { typedef Noddy base_type; };` I have realised I expect too much from PyObject, unless I implement custom compile-time machinery like trairts for PyObject. Thanks!

Comment: @mosklot: I just noticed that I misread a part of your question.  You actually want to avoid `NeverSeenNoddy` to be mistaken as a `Noddy`.  I thought you wanted to reinterpret something completely unrelated to `Noddy` as a `Noddy`, hence my talk about "design problems" etc.  Having realised this, I don't see what question actually remains.  Why doesn't `PyObject_IsInstance()` do the job?

Comment: Generally, `PyObject_IsInstance` does the job, but I wanted to be able to tell if `PyObject` is `Noddy` in situation and scope when `NoddyType` is not accessible. Noddy can be declared in a header included in number of .cpp files, but `NoddyType` name is local to particular translation unit. So, I brainstormed if it is possible to tell `PyObject` is related `Noddy` without access to `NoddyType` object. p.s. no idea why (at)sven-marnach does not link to your username, sorry.

Comment: Why not simply add an `extern PyTypeObject NoddyType` to the header?  If you need in in other translation units, just export it.  I'm seriously confused now.

Comment: @mloskot: Note that if you comment on my posts, you don't need an @... -- I will be notified anyway because it's my post.

Comment: Sven, ye sindeed. The extern (or a function returning PyObjectType per instance layout type) is what I do now. I was wondering if there is any other way to achieve it, so I asked this question. Because your answer comes to similar conclusions, thus it confirms the solution I have worked out so far, I mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Becuase every object starts with `PyObject_HEAD`, it is always safe to access the fields defined by this header. One of the fields is `ob_type` (usually accessed using the `Py_TYPE` macro). If this points to `NoddyType` or any other type derived from `NoddyType` (which is what `PyObject_IsInstance` tells you), then you can assume the object's layout is that of `struct Noddy`.

In other words, an object is compatible with `Noddy` instance layout if its `Py_TYPE` points to `NoddyType` or any of its subclasses.

In the second question, the cast wouldn't be fine. The layouts of `Noddy` and `NeverSeenNoddy` are different, even though the size might be the same.

Assuming that `NeverSeenNoddy` is layout of a `NeverSeenNoddy_Type` type, you should never cast to `NeverSeenNoddy` if `PyObject_IsInstance(obj, &NeverSeenNoddy_Type)` is false.

If you want to have two C-level types with common fields, you should derive both types from common base that has only the common fields in the instance layout.

The subtypes should then include the base layout at the top of their layouts:

```
struct SubNoddy {
    // No PyObject_HEAD because it's already in Noddy
    Noddy noddy;
    int extra_field;
};
```

Then, if `PyObject_IsInstance(obj, &SubNoddy_Type)` returns true, you can cast to `SubNoddy` and access the `extra_field` field.
If `PyObject_IsInstance(obj, &Noddy_Type)` returns true, you can cast to `Noddy` and access the common fields.

Comment: +1 as Similarly to Sven Marnach's answer, it helps me to realise mistakes in my assumptions about the PyObject and type objects.